# Formatting paragraphs with alignleft, alignright

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the "Who Are We" section to the left of the image. However, the "Meet the Team" section keeps popping up there for reasons unknown. Also, I don't know why but the "Meet the Team" section is split in half; one paragraph is on top next to the image and the other is below the "Who Are We" section.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ur080dmL/

HTML

```
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/Z9V9vWz.jpg" width="312" height="274" class="alignright">
<div class="team-bio alignleft">
  <h2>Who Are We?</h2>
  <p>Company Name is lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.</p>
  <p>Company Name is lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.</p>
  <p>Company Name is lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.</p>
</div>

<div class="single-bios">
  <h2>Meet the Team</h2>
  <div class="james-bio">James is lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt.</div>
  <div class="jason-bio">Jason is lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt.</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.alignright {
display: inline;
float: right;
margin-left: 1.5em;
}

.alignleft {
display: inline;
float: left;
margin-right: 1.5em;
}
```

Comment: Images are already inline elements, so remove that style. The reason is due to clearing. Look up floats and clearing, or float basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.alignleft  {

display: inline;
margin-right: 1.5em;    
}
```

Please try this. hope is will help you.

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no need to use float:left in this situation. If you completely take out float:left the problem should be fixed.